# Generator of evenly spaced points in a circle in python

Tags: python, generator, physics, geometry, points

I am tasked with generating evenly (more or less) spaced points on concentric rings of an invisible circle. The function should take a list of radii, and number of points to plot for a given radius as arguments. For example for a radius of 0 it should plot 1 point at (0,0). For a circle of radius of 1, it should plot 10 points along the circumference of the circle, spaced out by an angle of 2pi/10. For a circle of radius 2, 20 points along the circumference, spaced out by an angle of 2pi/20.

The generator should take the following parameters:

n, r_max, m

and should generate rings of coordinate pairs at radii

r_i = i*r_max/n      for i = 0,1,..,n.

Each ring should have n*i points uniformly distributed in θ where
n_i=1   for   i=0; n_i = mi for i>0

When the function is called like this:

```
for r, t in genpolar.rtuniform(n=10, rmax=0.1, m=6):
      plot(r * cos(t), r * sin(t), 'bo')
```

it should return a plot that looks like:
[image: Plot]

Here is what I've come up with so far:

```
def rtpairs(R, N):
        R=[0.0,0.1,0.2]
        N=[1,10,20]
        r=[]
        t=[]
        for i in N:
                theta=2*np.pi/i
            t.append(theta)

        for j in R:
            j=j
            r.append(j)

    plt.plot(r*np.cos(t),r*np.sin(t), 'bo')
    plt.show()
```

but I'm pretty sure there is a more efficient method using two for loops.

Many thanks

Answer (score 6):

I figured it out. The code goes like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

T = [1, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]
R = [0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6]



def rtpairs(r, n):

    for i in range(len(r)):
       for j in range(n[i]):    
        yield r[i], j*(2 * np.pi / n[i])

for r, t in rtpairs(R, T):
    plt.plot(r * np.cos(t), r * np.sin(t), 'bo')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to do this.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def circle_points(r, n):
    circles = []
    for r, n in zip(r, n):
        t = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, n, endpoint=False)
        x = r * np.cos(t)
        y = r * np.sin(t)
        circles.append(np.c_[x, y])
    return circles
```

When you pass this function in the appropriate lists, one with the radius for each circle and the other with the desired number of points it returns a list of coordinate arrays, one for each circle.

```
r = [0, 0.1, 0.2]
n = [1, 10, 20]
circles = circle_points(r, n)
```

These can be plotted as follows.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for circle in circles:
    ax.scatter(circle[:, 0], circle[:, 1])
ax.set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Here we see the result for more circles.

```
n = [1, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]
r = [0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6]
circles = circle_points(r, n)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for circle in circles:
    ax.scatter(circle[:, 0], circle[:, 1])
ax.set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to do the same with an ellipse?

Comment: @VictorAguiar Did you try to adjust the equations in `circle_points` that define `x = r * np.cos(t)` and `y = r * np.sin(t)`?  If you replace those with the equations for an ellipse, it should draw concentric ellipses.  I would have to check, but they may be an issue with spacing.

Comment: You need `np.linspace(0, two_pi, n, endpoint=False)` to have `n` angles evenly distributed around a circle. Otherwise, the start and end angle coincide. That's why the plots show 9 orange and 19 green dots.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way you could achieve this.

```
def circles(c_list: List[int]):
    g_d_list = []  # graph data list
    for g in c_list:
        # create length of circle list. In this instance
        # i'm multiplying by 8 each time but could be any number.
        lg = [g] * (8*g)
        ang = 360/len(lg)  # calculate the angle of each entry in circle list.
        ang_list = []
        for i in range(len(lg)+1):
            ang_list.append(ang*i)
        for i, c in enumerate(lg):
            # calculate the x and y axis points or each circle. in this instance
            # i'm expanding circles by multiples of ten but could be any number.
            x_axis = 0 + (10*g) * math.cos(math.radians(ang_list[i+1]))
            y_axis = 0 + (10*g) * math.sin(math.radians(ang_list[i+1]))
            # tuple structure ((axis tuple), circle size, circle colour)
            g_d_list.append(((x_axis, y_axis), 1, 'r'))

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    for c in range(len(g_d_list)):
        circle = plt.Circle(g_d_list[c][0], radius=g_d_list[c][1], fc=g_d_list[c][2])
        ax.add_patch(circle)
    plt.axis('scaled')
    plt.axis('off')  # optional if you don't want to show axis
    plt.show()
```

It produces a graph when provided with a list containing the number of circles you require. For example circles([1,2,3]) returns.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You do have to cycle through the entire circle for all radii, so your **plot** call is pretty much stuck with some M*N process.

The code details can be slightly improved.  For starters, your **R** list already holds the values you want; there's no need to construct a new list with the same values.  You can build the **t** list with a straightforward list comprehension.

Is this what you wanted?

```
    N=[1,10,20]
    t = [2*np.pi/i for i in N]
    for R in N:
        plt.plot(R*np.cos(t),R*np.sin(t), 'bo')

    plt.show()
```

Comment: No, it results in 3 rings of points -- the first of which is the degenerate center dot.

Comment: As written, this code ignores the input `N` and multiplies the list `R` by the `np.sin()` or `np.cos()`.  As @Lutzl mentions, I also only see 3 points when I run this code.  Could something have gotten changed when uploading the code you tested?

Comment: The "something" was including my simplified test case inside the function.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know python but this formula should help.

int ringNumber = 0

int n = ringNumber-1

((n/n+1)*60)-60 = degrees between points(except for ring zero, which the point is the center