# Plot random points a specified distance apart

Tags: numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to come up with a function that plots n points inside the unit circle, but I need them to be sufficiently spread out.

ie. something that looks like this:

[image]

Is it possible to write a function with two parameters, `n` (number of points) and `min_d` (minimum distance apart) such that the points are:

a) equidistant

b) no pairwise distance exceeds a given `min_d`

The problem with sampling from a uniform distribution is that it could happen that two points are almost on top of each other, which I do not want to happen. I need this kind of input for a network diagram representing node clusters.

---

EDIT: I have found an answer to a) here: [Generator of evenly spaced points in a circle in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33510979/generator-of-evenly-spaced-points-in-a-circle-in-python), but b) still eludes me.

Comment: Your question is too broad. What are the specific requirements? Since clearing the space around points effectively does not make them random any more, the question would be how much randomness do you still need? Apart from that, showing what you have tried so far does help others understanding the actual problem.

Comment: I have obtained the answer I was looking for by asking this question. If it was too broad, I apologize. How would you rephrase it?

Comment: Well, only you can know if my answer below answers the question. Objectively it cannot be determined, because the question is too broad. It is a wild guess. And for sure it doesn't mean that you should continue asking bad questions only because in this case you did obtain an answer.

Comment: How would you rephrase it?

Comment: As I said, how much randomness do you need, given that the points are not random under the given condition? Is there a requirement on the underlying distribution? Is there a fixed number of points that need to be plotted? What have you done to solve the problem? Which resources have you considered, in how far did they not help? What is the code that comes closest to what you want, at which point does it fail? Also see [ask].

Comment: Apologies- it's only just crossed my mind that there is a limit on how many points fit into the circle when you specify the minimum distance.
Do you have a way of always ensuring there are say, 60 points in the circle like this (choosing the minimum distance to support this?)

Comment: I have updated the answer to ensure that there is always found n points by stepwise decreasing the minimal distance. Note that this still draws random numbers. If the question is to find equidistant numbers, it's something completely different, and the answer of drawing random numbers is obsolete. Much better solutions for equidistant numbers are of course possible.

Answer (score 4):

*At the time this answer was provided, the question asked for random numbers. This answer thus gives a solution drawing random numbers. It ignores any edits made to the question afterwards.*

On may simply draw random points and for each one check if the condition of the minimum distance is fulfilled. If not, the point can be discarded. This can be done until a list is filled with enough points or some break condition is met.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Points():
    def __init__(self,n=10, r=1, center=(0,0), mindist=0.2, maxtrials=1000 ) :
        self.success = False
        self.n = n
        self.r = r
        self.center=np.array(center)
        self.d = mindist
        self.points = np.ones((self.n,2))*10*r+self.center
        self.c = 0
        self.trials = 0
        self.maxtrials = maxtrials
        self.tx = "rad: {}, center: {}, min. dist: {} ".format(self.r, center, self.d)
        self.fill()

    def dist(self, p, x):
        if len(p.shape) >1:
            return np.sqrt(np.sum((p-x)**2, axis=1))
        else:
            return np.sqrt(np.sum((p-x)**2))

    def newpoint(self):
        x = (np.random.rand(2)-0.5)*2
        x = x*self.r-self.center
        if self.dist(self.center, x) < self.r:
            self.trials += 1
            if np.all(self.dist(self.points, x) > self.d):
                self.points[self.c,:] = x
                self.c += 1

    def fill(self):
        while self.trials < self.maxtrials and self.c < self.n:
            self.newpoint()
        self.points = self.points[self.dist(self.points,self.center) < self.r,:]
        if len(self.points) == self.n:
            self.success = True
        self.tx +="\n{} of {} found ({} trials)".format(len(self.points),self.n,self.trials)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.tx


center =(0,0)
radius = 1 

p  = Points(n=40,r=radius, center=center)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x,y = p.points[:,0], p.points[:,1]

plt.scatter(x,y)
ax.add_patch(plt.Circle(center, radius, fill=False))

ax.set_title(p)
ax.relim()
ax.autoscale_view()
ax.set_aspect("equal")
plt.show()
```

[image]

If the number of points should be fixed, you may try to run find this number of points for decreasing distances until the desired number of points are found.

In the following case, we are looking for 60 points and start with a minimum distance of 0.6 which we decrease stepwise by 0.05 until there is a solution found. Note that this will not necessarily be the optimum solution, as there is only `maxtrials` of retries in each step. Increasing `maxtrials` will of course bring us closer to the optimum but requires more runtime.

```
center =(0,0)
radius = 1 
mindist = 0.6
step = 0.05
success = False
while not success:
    mindist -= step
    p = Points(n=60,r=radius, center=center, mindist=mindist)
    print p
    if p.success:
        break

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x,y = p.points[:,0], p.points[:,1]

plt.scatter(x,y)
ax.add_patch(plt.Circle(center, radius, fill=False))

ax.set_title(p)
ax.relim()
ax.autoscale_view()
ax.set_aspect("equal")
plt.show()
```

Here the solution is  found for a minimum distance of 0.15.

[image]